# Formatting Mollom using PHP code

Tags: php, captcha

I'm trying to implement the "***Mollom***" captcha service into a company website but am having some difficulty adding it into our existing site.

Looking at Mollom's documentation at : https://github.com/Mollom/MollomPHP I see that I need to take the `mollom.class.inc` file and call it from my main `keep_informed.php` file (http://dap.shenstorf.pl.internal/keep_informed.php).

I am not sure which parameters I need to set in my main php file or set in the `mollom.class.inc` file. All I come up with are HTTP Authentication Errors which I believe are due to not being able to contact Mollom's servers.

```
<?php
class MollomMyPlatform extends Mollom {

  public function loadConfiguration($name) {}

  public function saveConfiguration($name, $value) {}

  public function deleteConfiguration($name) {}

  public function getClientInformation() {}

  protected function request($method, $server, $path, $query = NULL, array $headers = array()) {}
}
```

The documentation also says to include this at the beginning of my `keep_informed.php` but never hints at whether or not these functions need to be filled out here or if it populates the values in `mollom.class.inc`, just that they need to be 'implemented'.

I've poured over the entire `mollom.class.inc` but it's hard to decipher which variables they expect to be left alone or changed. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated at this point!

Comment: Have you reached out to their support?  http://mollom.com/contact

Comment: Yes, another guy and I are working on this together and we both contacted their help/technical department. They haven't returned our emails for 3 days now.

Comment: My fellow conspirator found this thread and added our project to it. Figured I'd link it for those interested (https://github.com/Mollom/MollomPHP/issues/7)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you ever find the solution to your question? I have  the answer for you but I am not sure if you need it.